How to create non-tabulated data like word or PDF in oracle apex
How to create data object of descriptive data (Like word and PDF) in Oracle APEX.
It is possible to create a table format data in oracle APEX. But I want create non-tabulated data like word or PDF in oracle APEX. How write descriptive data (Like word and PDF) in Oracle APEX.

The first thing I can think of is to set item type to Rich text editor; result is then

Another option is to actually create document in e.g. MS Word and then upload it into a table (use BLOB datatype) via Apex.

Thank you, your quick reply. Applicable format for uploading is csv, xlsx, txt, xml and JSON only. How to upload MS word document?

I didn't say "load", but "upload" - use a **file browse" item type which lets you select any file type (JPEG, EXE, PDF, DOCX, whatever). You're - on the other hand - talking about Apex' capabilities of loading file contents directly into a table.

Data can be shown in many ways in APEX. And there are several ways to achieve that. If it is only displaying data then you can either write your own layout using a region of type "Dynamic Content", or you can have a look at the existing components that are just report templates but display the data in a non-table format. Best way to start is by investigating the available components in the universal theme.
